# taking one single data from response body in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Data",
    "data": [
        {
            "gtinNumber": "18903840000840",
            "batchNumber": "18222009",
            "consignmentNumber": "54782136548",
            "manufacturerName": null,
            "manufacturingDate": "30/09/2017",
            "experyDate": "30/09/2019",
            "fromSerialNumber": "100120",
            "toSerialNumber": "1000100",
            "concatFromSerialNumber": null,
            "concatToSerialNumber": "1000100NDADBLR10032",
            "date": "2018-09-15_14:17:42",
            "assignStatus": "assigned",
            "addDistributers": [
                {
                    "distributorId": "NDADBLR10032",
                    "distributorLocation": "Bangalore-BLR",
                    "receivedtime": "2018-09-17_09:08:47",
                    "packageStatus": "received",
                    "assignStatus": "notAssigned"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am always getting error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
>   cannot be cast to in.appface.ndaqrcodemanager.data

I just want to take the `assignStatus` from it

Comment: Please post your current attempt.

Comment: Can you please post relevant portion of your code?